# Homebrew and Fink in MacPorts diagnose output

Tags: macos, macports

I have compiled and installed MacPorts 2.5.4 at fresh installation on Mojave from source and getting on .git.
Nor Fink nor Homebrew, no junk of it, cause macOS is fresh.
Getting around a MacPorts build I have found next in the "diagnose" output with DEBUG option:

```
MBP:~ user$ > port -d diagnose
Checking for correct Xcode version... [SUCCESS]
Checking for for 'curl'... [SUCCESS]
Checking for for 'rsync'... [SUCCESS]
Checking for for 'openssl'... [SUCCESS]
Checking for for 'sqlite3'... [SUCCESS]
Checking for MacPorts' location... [SUCCESS]
Checking for free disk space... [SUCCESS]
Checking for dylibs in /usr/local/lib... [SUCCESS]
Checking for header files in /usr/local/include... [SUCCESS]
Checking for HomeBrew... [SUCCESS]
Checking for Fink... [SUCCESS]
Checking for stray developer directory... [SUCCESS]
Checking for compilation errors... [SUCCESS]
Checking for DYLD_* environment variables... [SUCCESS]
Checking for command line tools... [SUCCESS]
```

Can't find a proper description (manuals and discussions) on what depends on and what does it mean with:

```
Checking for HomeBrew... [SUCCESS]
Checking for Fink... [SUCCESS]
```

Please suggest...
Thank you